# Paramiko not returning stdout

Tags: python, ssh, paramiko

I'm using Paramiko to make a few SSH commands from a python program. The commands I am using are:

```
stdin, stdout, stderr = client.exec_command('ls')
print stdout
client.close()
```

however I'm getting the same output - it looks like a different data-type. Any ideas anybody? It's definitely not a list of files!

```
<paramiko.ChannelFile from <paramiko.Channel 0 (open) window=2097152 -> <paramiko.Transport at 0x801d6750L (cipher aes128-ctr, 128 bits) (active; 1 open channel(s))>>>
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Whoops - figured it out straight after. I forgot to do readlines() on stdout.
So, before the print statement I should have:
`stdout = stdout.readlines()`